# How to find common edges from a binary dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, group-by, multiple-columns

This is my dataset:

| Dept | Cell culture | Bioinfo | Immunology | Trigonometry | Algebra | Biotech | Optics |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Biotech | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Math | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Physics | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

How I want my result:

| Dept | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| Biotech | Cell culture |
| Biotech | Bioinfo |
| Biotech | Immunology |
| Math | Trigonometry |
| Math | Algebra |
| Physics | Optics |

I need to form pairs that have the value one, but I also need to rid of those values which are the same in both column and row index - such as biotech here. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#df = df.set_index('Dept') if needed move dept into the index
df.dot(df.columns+',').str.strip(',').str.split(',').explode().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
      Dept             0
0  Biotech  Cell culture
1  Biotech       Bioinfo
2  Biotech    Immunology
3  Biotech       Biotech
4     Math  Trigonometry
5     Math       Algebra
6  Physics        Optics
```

Comment: This works! But is there any way to remove pairs like Biotech-biotech? Since they are identical, I don't want them in my result dataset!

Comment: Drop the column before the operation or figure where dept == 0.